# Python Pandas - How to substitue a column of DataFrame1 with the values of a column in DataFrame2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi All I have a Dataframe with more than 50000 records. It has a column by name "Country" which has duplicate values.

As part of a Machine Learning project I am doing a Label Encoding on this column which will replace this column with 50000 records with integer values. (ok for those who do not know about Label Encoding - it takes the unique values of the column and assign an integer value to it mostly based on alphabetical order but not sure though). Say this Dataframe is DF1 and column is "Country".

**Now my requirement is that I have to do the same for another dataframe (DF2) manually i.e without using the Label Encoding function**.

What I have tried so far and where do I get struck is mentioned below

- I have taken the unique values of DF1.Country column and kept in a
  new dataframe(temp_df).
- Tried to do right join of DF2 and temp_df keeping on="Country". But getting "NaN" in few records. Not sure why
- Tried to do find-and-replace using .isin method but still not getting
  desired output.

**So my basic question is how to fill a column in a dataframe with the values of a column in another dataframe by matching the values of two columns in two dataframes ?**

**UPDATED**

Sample code output is given below for better understanding

The Country Column in DF2 has repeatable values like this :

```
0        us
1        us
2        gb
3        us
4        au
5        fr
6        us
7        us
8        us
9        us
10       us
11       us
12       ca
13       at
14       us
15       us
16       es
17       fi
18       fr
19       us
20       us
```

The temp_df dataframe will have integer value for every unique country name like mentioned below (Note : This dataframe will only have unique values. Not duplicates) :

```
1          gb           49
2          ca           22
3          au            5
4          de           34
5          fr           48
6          br           17
7          jp           75
8          sv          136
9          no          111
10         se          132
11         es           43
12         nl          110
13         mx          103
14         dk           36
15         ro          127
16         ch           24
17         it           71
18         be           10
19         ru          129
20         kr           78
21         fi           44
22         hk           59
23         ie           65
24         sg          133
25         nz          112
26         ar            3
27         at            4
28         in           68
29         cl           26
30         il           66
```

**Now I have to create a new column in DF2 by taking the integer values from temp_df for each country value in DF2. Hope this helps.**

Comment: Please add a minimal example, such as few row data from your dataframes and what you want to achieve.

Comment: And an attempt at the problem, as this website is not for free coding servies

Comment: Create a `dict` for the mapping, and then use that to replace the column `Country`
`country_map = {'France': 1, 'Spain': 2}`
`df.replace({'Country': country_map })`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Will add the code snippet

Comment: @djk47463 I know this site is not for free coding services. Neither do i need one. I already mentioned what I attempted. Only thing is I did not include the output here as it is large. anyways thanks for your suggestion. Will follow going forward

Comment: I think it would be very useful if you post your code and a small excerpt from your data. Just `print(df.sample(15))` and add those strings to your question. it's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Updated the question. Hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pandas.Series.map` to accomplish this:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# Your data ..
data = """
    id,country
    0,AT
    1,DE
    2,UK
    3,FR
    4,AT
    5,UK
    6,IT
    7,DE
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep=',', index_col=[0])

# Create a map from your current labels to numeric labels:
country_labels = dict([(c, i) for i, c in enumerate(df.country.unique())])

# Use map() to transform your column and re-assign it
df.country = df.country.map(lambda c: country_labels[c])

print(df)
```

which will transform the above data to

```
        country
    id         
0             0
1             1
2             2
3             3
4             0
5             2
6             4
7             1
```

As suggested in one of the comments to your question, you could also use `replace()`

```
df = df.replace({'country': country_labels })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country' : ['z','x', 'x', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'Something' : [10, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]})

# create dictionary for mapping `sorted` countries to integer
country_map = dict(zip(sorted(df.Country.unique()), range(len(df.Country.unique()))))
# country_map should look smthing like:
# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'x': 3, 'z': 4}, where a, b, .. are countries

# replace `Country` coloumn with mapping
df.replace({'Country': country_map })
```

Comment: good one @dimitris_ps. But my requirement is I have to compare the value of Col1 in DF2 with the country_map keys and fetch the corresponding country_map values which will be put in Col2 in DF2. Please note that the values of Col1 in DF2 is duplicated. So wherever the same value is present, the corresponding integer should be same

Comment: @JKC I am not sure i am following. you are just talking about a join then. The fact that you are getting NaN is because the country name in DF2 does not exist in the temp_df. Maybe a sampled data set would be good to have in your question.

Comment: @JKC In your question you state that you want to replace the labels with integer values. If you just want to add this as a second column then you can just assign the result from `map()` to a new column.

Comment: @JKC Or dimitris_ps is right about the fact that you're actually talking about a join. In this case you should give [Merge, join and concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) a read.

Comment: @dimitris_ps yes that's also a possiblity. few values present in DF2 might not be available in temp_df. I will replace those values with zero or some other number. That's not a problem. Updated the question for better clarity. Hope that makes more clear

Comment: Oh yes . My mistake. My apologies.  I was doing "right" join keeping temp_df to the right . So I was getting wrong. Now I changed it to "Left" and it works fine. But the missing values are coming as "NaN'. I am replacing them with zeroes using the command DF2.fillna(0) but it makes all the values in that column as a float. How to convert this to integer. any idea ?

Comment: @JKC `df.thecol = df.thecol.astype(int)`